# PHP MYSQL Multiple drop downs Select value on change

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have fetched product sizes and quantity from a table and showed them in dropdown lists.Depending on products the drop downs may vary from 5 to 6.I want to get the value of size id from the drop down when a user selects it from the drop down and put it as value in the input type number.

```
<select name='size' id='size' class='form-control'>

      <option value="1">Small</option>

  </select>

<input type='number' name='quantity' min='1' value='1' class='form-control' />
<select name='size' id='size' class='form-control'>

      <option value="2">Large</option>

  </select>

<input type='number' name='quantity' min='1' value='1' class='form-control' />

<select name='size' id='size' class='form-control'>

      <option value="3">XLarge</option>

  </select>

<input type='number' name='quantity' min='1' value='1' class='form-control' />
```

The jquery I am using is as follows,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#size").change(function() {
            var str = "";
            $("select option:selected").each(function() {
                str += $(this).val() + " ";
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I am getting values form first dropdown but can not get from other dropdowns.
Kindly help

Comment: Where are your other dropdowns? Likely it's because you have multiple `id="size"` which will only work on the first instance. `id` are meant to be unique. Use the class as the selector.

Comment: thanks for your reply.I am get the other dropdowns in loop with name and id as 'size'.spent alot of time but did not come to any conclusion...

Comment: You can not have multiple ids with the same name. You need to use the class instead

Comment: @MuhammadMaaz, From one select you want to select multiple option?

Comment: No, I want to get the value when ever any dropdown value is selected

Comment: okey, i am going to add your answer.

Comment: @MuhammadMaaz, Check out my answer, I already did it.

Comment: you have only one dropdown in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussion i did a fiddle to give the solution [Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/frayne_konok/cfovkwkv/)

**Updated JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".size").on("change", function() {
        $(this).closest("div").find("input").val($(this).val());
    });
});
```

If you want to get the `$row['size']` when select any option then you have to change your `PHP` code also.

**Updated PHP**

```
<div>
<select name='size' class='form-control size'>
    <?php foreach ($rows as $row) {?>
      <option value="<?php echo $row['size']?>" <?php if ($row['quantity'] == 0) echo "disabled=disabled"?>>
        <?php echo $row['size']?>
      </option>
        <?php }?>
</select>
<input type='number' name='quantity' min='1' value='1' class='form-control' />
</div>
<div>
<select name='size' class='form-control size'>
    <?php foreach ($rows as $row) {?>
      <option value="<?php echo $row['size']?>" <?php if ($row['quantity'] == 0) echo "disabled=disabled"?>>
        <?php echo $row['size']?>
      </option>
        <?php }?>
</select>
<input type='number' name='quantity' min='1' value='1' class='form-control' />
</div>
```

> **Note:** `$(this).val()` get the selected value from the drop down and put the value into the input field by
>   `$(input[name=quantity]).val()`
>   I put the `$row['size']` to the `option value`

**Let me know is it helpful to you or not.**

Comment: thanks for the help.Its working fine on the first instance.Dont work on the other dropdowns plus when first dropdown value is selected it changes the quantity value for all other input types as well

Comment: depends on the products added.Each product has a quantity and size value.What I want is to get value from the drop down and add it as a value in the input type number.

Comment: loop is finished just above the input type number,thats why iam unable to get the quantity value

Comment: which loop?? do you mean foreach? If it is then its not fact.

Comment: IF you want to select multiple option from one select box then the answer will be different.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104509/discussion-between-frayne-konok-and-muhammad-maaz).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<td>
    <select name='size' id='size' class='form-control'>
          <?php foreach ($rows as $row) {?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['id']?>" <?php if ($row['quantity'] == 0) echo "disabled=disabled"?> >
                <?php echo $row['size']?>
            </option>
          <?php }?>
        </select>
</td>
<td>
    <input type='number' name='quantity' min='1' value='1' class='form-control' />
</td>
```

Comment: please add some description, its better to guess other that where you change or what you do.

Comment: @FrayneKonok, I am sorry for the description. I am getting the drop down from db using loop.Below is an input type number. I want to get value from on change event from the dropdown selected and put as a max value in the input type.Every time I get the values from the first instance,not from the other dropdowns.

Comment: @MuhammadMaaz, Here i comment for `noushid` not you.

Answer (score -1):

Your dropdown id should be different as you know id is unique for one element in a document.